# Practice Unix on Windows Machine

Tags: windows, shell, unix, scripting, windows-vista

I want to practice Unix (mostly KornShell (ksh) scripting and VI editor) on a windows Vista machine. What is the best solution for this? I do not like Cygwin. So anything other than Cygwin which gives the closest feel of Unix Environment without re-installing the OS.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with cygwin? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Carl, For some weird reason I dont like cygwins interface. I will give it a shot. Can I practice Korn Shell Scripting on Cygwin? How does installing Unix on VMWare works?

Comment: Check out rxvt under Cygwin - it's a *huge* improvement over the default terminal window.

Comment: Is this really a programming question, strictly speaking? I dunno how fascist we are about programming-related questions here on SO. :-/

Comment: Well its not. I apologize if this question is real stupid.

Comment: @t3ch It's not a stupid question by any means, but I know that some people are a little more committed to keeping SO programming-related than others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Cygwin is really the easiest way to get what you're asking for, but another option might be [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).  (Minimalist GNU for Windows).

If you just want to practice with specific command-line utilities, you could also look at:  [Unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Like others have said, you could also use a VM to install some type of Unix/Linux OS, like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

You can set up a virtual machine using VMware Player. http://www.vmware.com/products/player/
It lets you run a real *nix environment inside of Windows. It's free, and fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

Solo es una sugerencia:

Why don't try instaling a virtual machine and then some unix?

Just a little suggestion

Comment: Hi chepe, I do have VMware player on my machine, what flavor of Unix should I go for?

Comment: To each his own, but the most popular *nix OS out there right now, hands-down, is Ubuntu. I'd give that a shot. Chepe might have another recommendation. ;)

Comment: like Ben Torell says, try ubuntu. In fact, i'm running ubuntu right now. IF you want to play with it and feel how does it work on your machine try installing. There's a tool on the disc to install ubuntu inside windows. Also, if you have an extra usb pendrive, try installing ubuntu on it. It's great!

Comment: Hi Ben, Andy also suggested Ubuntu.. so I guess I will go for this. Does VMware player runs real slow on windows machine with 4gig RAM.

Comment: pen drive idea is great. will do that. I still need Vmware player thought. right?

Answer (score 3):

Get **vim** for Windows for vi practice (then get vim for your actual Unix box) and get Cygwin for a shell environment plus Unix utilities.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I will download vim for windows. Can we install unix using VMware?

Comment: Good god. Of course you can. That's, like, have the frucking point of VMWare.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.elitter.net/

Free shell accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the *best* way to practice it on your Windows machine is to install a virtual machine (e.g. [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/), it's free) and set up Linux on that one. Then have them communicate through e.g. a shared folder.

But then there often are Windows clones of many of the most popular software on Unix/Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good alternative to Cygwin, try [UWIN](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/tools/uwin/).

More information on it can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWIN).

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest that you download a version of unix. Here are some suggestions:

1. [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/) 
2. [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/) 
3. [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/)

After downloading one of these, use virtualbox or vmware and install them in a virtual machine.

1. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) 
2. [VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0) 
This way you can easily run UNIX in a virtual environment and practice it easily. It's the most convenient method.

Also if you want you can install arch Linux which is very small and then install ksh shell in it using pacman and then change your default shell from bash to korn by this command `chsh -s /bin/ksh`. You can do all this in other Linux distributions too. Also if you are only looking for working with shell and vim you can use `Ubuntu-server` then install KornShell in it as well using `sudo apt-get install ksh`. It's entirely up to you which option do you wanna take.